# AHK recursive map? (Map RAlt to RWin which is mapped to other keys)

Tags: autohotkey, keymapping, alt-key, windows-key

I have a bunch of `RWin+X => Y` mappings. I would like `RAlt` to be mapped to `RWin` so that `RWin+X` == `RAlt+X`. For example:

```
; RWin+J => Left
>#j::SendInput,{LEFT}
```

Which works fine, I can hold down `RWin` and press `j` and it would keep sending `Left`. Now let's add before that map the following:

```
RAlt::RWin
```

If I hold `RAlt` then press `j`, it would send a `Left` correctly, but if I keep holding `RAlt` and press `j` again, it would send a `j` and not `Left`. I would have to release `RAlt` and press it again.

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why can't you assign the same action to both keys?

Comment: Well I had some issues mapping `RAlt`, for example I have this map `>#^!j::SendInput,^!{LEFT}` - which maps `RWin+Ctrl+Alt+j` to `Ctrl+Alt+Left` - problem is If I use `>!` instead of `>#` ahk gets confused because there's two Alts now involved. I tried specifying that I want `<!` instead of `!` can't remember exactly what it gave me but it's either an error or it got confused again giving me erroneous maps. RWin was working fine so I thought I'd map RAlt to it because it's easier to press and puts less strain on my hand. I might just go with the RAlt maps and ignore the ones that has `!`

Comment: Could it be that your keyboard has an AltGr key instead of a right-Alt key? http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols

Answer (score 1):

This what I came up with based on your issue. It's a work around solution:

```
#J::
If (GetKeyState("RAlt", "P") Or GetKeyState("RWin", "P")) {
    SendInput,{LEFT}
}
Return

RAlt::
While GetKeyState("RAlt", "P") {
        ; Add any Key in {Key} format followed by Period . that you want to act as an EndKey.
        Input, Key, L1 M T1, {space}.{esc}.{shift}.{enter}
                         .{tab}.{backspace}.{alt}.{home}
                         .{delete}.{pgup}.{pgdn}.{end}
                         .{up}.{down}.{left}.{right}
            If (Key <> "") {
                SendInput, {RWin down}{%Key%}{Rwin Up}
                }
            If InStr(ErrorLevel, "EndKey:") 
                Send % "{" . StrReplace(ErrorLevel, "EndKey:") . "}"
    }
Return
```

Comment: `Error: Too few parameters passed to function. Specifically: StrReplace(ErrorLevel, "EndKey:") . "}"``

Comment: Are you using the latest version of AutoHotkey? Works fine on my system.